Best practice to compute contrasts from Bayesian posterior with repeats
I have samples ($i$) from posterior distributions of a parameter ($\theta$) for two different conditions $a$ and $b$.
Samples of the posterior difference between the two conditions $\theta_{\delta i}$ would require simply subtracting the posterior of condition b from condition a: ($\theta_{\delta i} = \theta_{bi} - \theta_{ai}$).
However, I have posterior samples from $r$ repeats for each condition i.e. $\theta_{ai}^1, \theta_{ai}^2, ... \theta_{ai}^r$, and  $\theta_{bi}^1, \theta_{bi}^2, ... \theta_{bi}^r$.
I know that ideally to compute $\theta_{\delta}$ I should have a hierarchical formulation where the effect of each repeat for a condition shares some hyperprior, and then I would just compute the contrast using the hyperprior samples of $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$.
But, if all I have to work with are the posterior samples from the repeats (e.g. $\theta_{ai}^1, \theta_{ai}^2, ... \theta_{ai}^r$), what is the best way to compute samples for $\theta_{\delta}$?
Options I've considered:

Pair up repeats. I.e. compute $\theta_{\delta i}^1 = \theta_{bi}^1 - \theta_{ai}^1$, $\theta_{\delta i}^2 = \theta_{bi}^2 - \theta_{ai}^2$ etc... then stack all the $\theta_{\delta i}^1, \theta_{\delta i}^2$, ... together to create $\theta_{\delta i}$. This is fine but if there is a different number of repeats for each condition then not all repeats would be used.
Similar to 1, but instead of making pairs of repeats of $\theta_i$ for each condition, compute all pairwise combinations of repeats. This way all repeats for all conditions get used, and all repeats get compared against each other. But the posterior samples of conditions with fewer repeats get used more, which feels wrong.

Are there other ways of doing this? What would be best? (Or least worst?)
Thanks for any advice!
